# Android - Display button with sharedpreference value

Tags: android, android-spinner

I'm currently working in an Activity which saves text from Button1...button8.

But it not display text of button.i don't understand.

MainActivity=>

```
public void getName(){
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("sample",0);
    int a=(preferences.getInt("num",0));
    String ab=(preferences.getString("Name",""));
    if(a==0){
        button1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        button1.setText(ab);
    }
    if(a==1){
        button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        button2.setText(ab);
    }
    if(a==3){
        button3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        button3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        button3.setText(ab);
    }
}
```

SetupActivity=>

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Sample", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString("Name", editText.getText().toString());
    editor.putInt("num", myNum);
    editor.commit();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Setup.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Check your Preference Names, you are using

```
getSharedPreferences("Sample", 0);
```

and

```
getSharedPreferences("sample",0);
```

Comment: Well debug your code and specify your problem. For example has "a" the value you expect? Is editText.getText().toString() not "". Are the preferences overwritten?

Answer (score 1):

> not display text of button

That because (preferences.getString("Name","") return " " as default and this is probably the case.

In addition the lines:

```
 button_.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 button_.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

is really not make sense. you can drop the line:

```
button_.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: What you mean in "not save"?

Comment: sorry,i have litter english,it mean  no save button text.

Comment: Where it not saved?in onClick? you checked id your editText not empty?

Comment: sure,my mean is button no saved permanently,it always change when i click exits button

Comment: You mean when you return to the MainActivity after you exit?

Answer (score 1):

First remove this line from the getName method

> button_.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Then check out the KEY  you are using to save the name of buttons in your case You are saving with the name of Sample and retrieving it as sample. Keep it mind key is case sensitive.

Now coming to other point in case you wrote key "Sample" just to demonstrate us the question. Before starting I would like to ask you where are you calling your method getName in mainActivity. But anyways here are the secure way of doing this:

When saving your button names add these lines

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Sample", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        if(editText.getText().toString().length()>0){
        editor.putString("Name", editText.getText().toString());
        editor.putInt("num", myNum);
        editor.commit();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Setup.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);}
}
```

and in getName method just do this

```
public void getName(){
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("sample",0);
    int a=(preferences.getInt("num",0));
    String ab=(preferences.getString("Name",""));
   if(a==0){
       button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       button1.setText(ab);
    }
   if(a==1){
       button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       button2.setText(ab);
    }
   if(a==3){
       button3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       button3.setText(ab);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you.but i don't know,i saved text of button1,but when i click "edit" button=>button1 return the same,button2 saved.:(

Comment: what do you mean , please explain

Comment: sorry ,i have litter english.it mean : i want saving text of button when i click "edit" button.